# Automating an Excel Macro

Tags: vb.net, excel

Here is a macro I generated using the record macro feature in excel.

```
    Range("A11").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("B11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A12").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("D11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A13").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("E11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A14").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("F11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A12:A14").Select
    Range("A14").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A12").Select
```

I am not very good with Excel or visual basic.
I want to run this code for about 400 rows more. So I need to Automate this even more.
So here is my plan:
I will use some broken codes. I don't know how to write in visual basic so can someone correct the code so that the syntax is correct? 'n' is a variable, which I will set later

```
    Range("An").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("Bn").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A(n+1)").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("Dn").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A(n+2)").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("En").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A(n+3)").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("Fn").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A(n+1):A(n+3)").Select
    Range("A(n+3)").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A(n+1)").Select
```

Comment: You would use a loop over **n** _________also the correct syntax is **Range("D" & n).Select** rather than **Range("Dn").Select**

Comment: What do you mean by loop over n?
Thanks for the syntax :)

Comment: Ah pnuts. Yeah, Macros seems easier than the other method you suggested earlier. Because it's just automating something I can do manually. It feels Natural. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to **Loops,** consider a small part of your code:

```
Range("A11").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("B11").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

suppose we wish to repeat this for rows 12 thru 578.  We would use a loop:

```
Sub Aiman()
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 11 To 578
        Range("A" & n).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Range("B" & n).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next n
End Sub
```

The block of code between **For** and **Next** is executed for n= 11,12,13,....578

The logic can be optimized further by removing the **Select** s

Comment: Thanks. I know what For loops are I actually didn't understand why you said that until I ran the code and found out it ran once :v.

Thank you so much. I have got the work done now!

Comment: If you need more help on this specific project, just update the question.